# Getting the origin (absolute path) of a uploaded file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, absolute-path

In my django app I ask for files. The user can select multiple audio files via:

```
django.forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})
```

However, for my use case the absolute file paths were the selected files originated from is important. When I access the files with `request.FILES.getlist()`, I can only see the name of the selected file, but not the full path.

How do I get the absolute paths?

Comment: You can't, why do you want it?

Comment: So the selected files are the processed and some metrics calculated. However, sometimes people dont know which file they selected. Imagine you select 2 files named results.txt, then these are processed. The only association I have is the file name, which is equal. So I cant distinguish them anymore. The original path would be important for that, so you know what was uploaded: /project_1/results.txt,  /project_2/results.txt